# Get Runtime Type picked by implicit evidence

Tags: scala, implicit

Suppose I have a set of converters to String, as a Type class:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

abstract class ToStringConverter[T] { 
    def convert(value: T): String 
}
implicit object IntToStringConverter extends ToStringConverter[Int] { 
     def convert(value: Int) = value.toString 
}
implicit object DoubleStringConverter extends ToStringConverter[Double] {
     def convert(value: Double) = value.toString 
}
```

and a convert method that uses the type information to pick right converter:

```
def convert[T](v: T)(implicit ev: ToStringConverter[T]): String = ev.convert(v)
```

This works fine If I have the concrete type in advance, for example:

```
scala> convert[Double](12.2)
res0: String = 12.2

scala> convert[Int](12)
res1: String = 12
```

Is it possible to use the convert method above with a runtime type, for example, with a type 't' below?

```
scala> val t = typeOf[Double]
t: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = Double
```

Comment: Your `convert` expects a value as a parameter - what would you want to do with `t`? If you want to call `convert(t)`, you can provide `implicit object RTUStringConverter extends ToStringConverter[runtime.universe.Type]` easily.

Comment: The convert method is currently expecting a type parameter, and this type is used to bring in the scope the right converter via implicit mechanism.

Sometimes I don't know the type in advance, I only have a Type that represents it, so should I change the signature to pass in the Type instance, and manually obtain somehow the implicit converter for that type?

Comment: You want to call it in a way like `val a: Any;convert[t](a)`?

Comment: Something along this line, or maybe passing the type as a second parameter, but had no luck getting the implicit evidence satisfied with only a runtime Type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do the resolution runtime, reflection is needed, as implicits are resolved compile time. A code like this should do the job:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

abstract class ToStringConverterAny {
  def convertAny(value: Any): String
}

abstract class ToStringConverter[T] extends ToStringConverterAny {
  def convertAny(value: Any): String = convert(value.asInstanceOf[T])
  def convert(value: T): String
}
implicit object IntToStringConverter extends ToStringConverter[Int] {
  def convert(value: Int) = value.toString
}
implicit object DoubleStringConverter extends ToStringConverter[Double] {
  def convert(value: Double) = value.toString
}

val converters: Map[Type, ToStringConverterAny] = Map(
  typeOf[Int] -> IntToStringConverter,
  typeOf[Double] -> DoubleStringConverter
)

def convert(t: Type, v: Any) = {
  converters(t).convertAny(v)
}

def convert[T](v: T)(implicit ev: ToStringConverter[T]): String = ev.convert(v)

convert[Double](12.2)

convert[Int](12)

val t = typeOf[Double]
val v: Any = 1.23

convert(t, v)
```

If you want to building `converters` map automatically, you could also use reflection for this, but enumerating derived classes requires surprisingly non-trivial code (including class loaders - which is understandable when you think about it).

If you can make the `ToStringConverterAny` sealed, enumerating over its subclasses in a macro should be a bit easier.

Comment: This works fine, but I was wondering (as the title of the question says) if I can get the converter via implicit mechanism rather than having a Map, I guess not

Comment: implicits are compile time only. You need something like the map for the runtime dispatch. The maximum you could do would be to build a map compile time using macros (compile time reflection) by reflecting on the implicits somehow.